# Reference for model structure on CosimplicialAbelianGroups

Tags: model-categories, reference-request

There is a standard (simplicial) model category structure on the category $Ab^\Delta \simeq Ch^\bullet_+(Ab)$ of *co*-simplicial abelian groups, whose fibrations are the *degreewise surjections* (and weak equivalences are the usual quasi-isos).

My question is about proper attribution: where does this first appear in citable form?. What is the canonical reference you would cite?